# lyx: table goes out the page margin

Tags: tables, lyx, margins

[image]

how to solve this problem?
I tried to change the font size and text width and none helped

Comment: It would be easier to help with a minimal compilable code. Clearly your table is too wide for the page size.

Comment: Cross-posted [here](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=27267). Please read [this](http://latex-community.org/home/latex-community/94-etiquette/454-crossposts) for why it is important to note your other posts.

Answer (score 2):

I'd simply transpose the table - columns for the four forces, their properties in separate rows. You probably don't need the word 'force' in "Weak nuclear" and "Strong nuclear". And please (please!) use Formal Style for your tables - that's an option in Table Settings dialog.

Comment: excuse me, where can I find Table Properties Dialog to use Formal Style for tables ?

Comment: Edit>Table Settings>Borders tab>Style:Formal while the cursor is inside the table

Answer (score 1):

you can change the font size to smallest.
and you can change the columns width by right button in the mouse ( on the table ).